# Linq To XML delete document from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file. Here is a short part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<documents>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1001</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>Mark Sweden</name>
            <cf>AAABBBCCC</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1002</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>John Car</name>
            <cf>AAABBBVVV</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1004</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>Mark Sweden</name>
            <cf>AAABBBCCC</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
</documents>
```

I would like to delete, using Linq to XML, every single document that has a particular "cf" value.
For example if "cf" value is AAABBBCCC first and third documents would be deleted.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

My problem was to get the documents to delete (the linq query I wrote was wrong). Robert McKee pointed me to the right direction.
My solution is:

```
var Delete = (from x in doc.Descendants(document)
where x.Descendants("cf").First().Value = "AAABBBCCC"
select x);

Delete.Remove();
```

Comment: What code did you try and where are you blocked. Pleases share the code you are trying.

Comment: That's not a query, that's a modification and as such, you can not do what you asked, however, you can probably use LINQ to return a (different) result without those documents, or you can also probably query for the documents that match your criteria and loop over them, and remove them from the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xml=@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<documents>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1001</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>Mark Sweden</name>
            <cf>AAABBBCCC</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1002</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>John Car</name>
            <cf>AAABBBVVV</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
    <document>
        <head>
            <date>01/01/2015</date>
            <nr>1004</nr>
        </head>
        <body>
            <name>Mark Sweden</name>
            <cf>AAABBBCCC</cf>
        </body>
    </document>
</documents>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach(var node in var node in doc.Descendants("document").Where(d=>d.Descendants("cf").First().Value=="AAABBBCCC").ToArray())
{
    node.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: it should be almost auto-explicative, but let me know any doubts

```
var root = XElement.Load(myPath);
List<XElement> deleteMe = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var item in root.Elements())
{
    if (item.Element("body").Element("cf").Value.Equals(myCf))
    {
        deleteMe.Add(item);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Deleting: " + String.Join(",",deleteMe.Select(x => x.Element("head").Element("nr").Value)));
Console.ReadKey();
foreach (var item in deleteMe)
{
    item.Remove();
}
root.Save(myPath2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XDocument, you can generate a copy of your document without the undesired elements, and then overwrite the original file:

```
string documentPath;
string undesiredPattern = "AAABBBCCC";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(documentPath);
//Or, if your document is already loaded on a string, use XDocument.Parse(string)
XElement root = xdoc.Root;

IEnumerable<XElement> desiredElements = 
 root.
 Elements().
 Where(x=>!x.Element("body").Element("cf").Value.Equals(undesiredPattern));

XDocument newDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
XElement newRoot = new XElement("documents");
foreach(XElement xe in desiredElements)
{
  newRoot.Add(xe);
}
newDoc.Add(newRoot);
newDoc.Save(documentPath);
```

Edit:
Other way, more direct (if you want to load from file, instead of XDocument.Parse use the XDocument.Load and XDocument.Save to save afterwards, as the piece above):

```
string document = "your xml";
string undesiredPattern = "AAABBBCCC";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(document);

xdoc.Root.Elements().Where(x=>
  x.Element("body").
  Element("cf").Value.
  Equals(undesiredPattern)).Remove();
```